# Nav going into footer

Tags: css

[On my page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/computer-services/computer-repairs/pc-recovery-brentwood-501.html), the left-nav is going into the footer and I'm not sure why.

If anyone could take a look using and inspector that'd be great as there's lots of CSS & html. But if you need it, please let me know and I'll paste it in.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with `id="footer-wrapper"` has negative `margin-top`.

Set `#footer-wrapper { margin-top:0; }`